# How do I implement a Timer on this MVC setup?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Using Java Spring, I have a page which pulls a random auction listing from its database, and refreshes this action every time the user refreshes the browser.

Instead, I want to make it show the same randomly chosen auction for all users, switching to a new random one every hour. ("Here is this hour's featured auction!")

Here is how my current flow works:

1. Data.xml pulls in random auction from db.
2. DAO created from sql import
3. public List created from DAO, does a few special things here with the data.
4. List from that List created in page controller, added to a MVC map for use on front end.

Kind of running out of time here, so I'm just going to create a kind of stop valve on this, so it only gets the data once every hour instead of on request.

Not asking for code here, but a strategy. Should I go with a CronTrigger? And where should the job be?

(Thanks :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like [new Spring caching support](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/23/spring-3-1-m1-caching/) might be helpful: set cache time to live to 1 hour with condition (or clear it manually with any scheduler).

Comment: Yeah, but that would be too front end. Like really front end. Like it would vary computer to computer.